# 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.4.0,4.0.0)' could not be found

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am trying to install an in-house plugin that I has installed several time before but this time I am getting these errors:

Does it mean it is not compatible with the new EClipse Juno I am using?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Maven 2 Tools 2.0.1 (com.Company.engineering.maven.feature.feature.group 2.0.1)

  Missing requirement: Maven 2 Tools 2.0.1 (com.Company.engineering.maven.feature.feature.group 2.0.1) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.4.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

Comment: It's saying your feature has defined a range on the org.eclipse.platform feature.  If you remove the upper limit, you would be able to test your tool on Juno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your in-house plugin is not compatible with the default Eclipse Juno distribution, which is built on Eclipse 4.2.  You can see that in your plugin:(com.Company.engineering.maven.feature.feature.group) there is dependency on the Eclipse Platform from [3.4.0, 4.0.0).  This means that you plugin will work with Eclipse 3.4 up-to (but not including) 4.0.0.

You have two options here:

1. Update your plugin.  There is a compatibility layer between Eclipse 3.x and 4.x, so you might just need to update the version ranges in your dependency. This assumes you have access to com.Company.engineering.maven.feature.feature.group.
2. Use Eclipse 3.8 as your base. You can get this from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.html.  However, this will be the last Eclipse release based on 3.x, so you should consider updating soon.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Juno is Eclipse 4.2 and is thus is not compatible with your plugin. You can try Eclipse 3.8.1 from [this page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.html).

Answer (score 1):

My Eclipse is 4.2.2, and the error disappear when i updated the Eclipse with the link 'http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2'.