# Aptana Studio 3 and Twig plugin

Tags: symfony, plugins, twig, aptana

So I am trying to install Twig plugin from http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org but getting this message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Twig Editor Feature 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.201309142024)
Missing requirement: com.dubture.twig.core 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.core 1.0.13.201309142024) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Twig Editor Feature 1.0.13.201309142024 (com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.13.201309142024)
To: com.dubture.twig.core [1.0.13.201309142024]
```

Is there a solution to that problem?

Comment: That works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362283/eclipse-code-fomatting

Comment: possible duplicate of ['org.eclipse.platform.feature.group \[3.4.0,4.0.0)' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643852/org-eclipse-platform-feature-group-3-4-0-4-0-0-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

These plugins are compatible with Eclipse 3.4 up-to (but not including) 4.0.0 so... you can't install it on Aptana 3.

I found answer here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643852/org-eclipse-platform-feature-group-3-4-0-4-0-0-could-not-be-found)